# Event-based multithread producer-consumer?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, producer-consumer

I wish to figure out how to create a multithreaded producer/consumer program where producing is based on an external event.

I have built a synchronized queue having 2 thread loops, one to enqueue and one to dequeue and write into a file, with classic pattern:

```
Class SyncQueue  
{
    ...
    producerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartProducer));
    consumerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartConsumer));
    ...

    public void Start()
    {
        producerThread.Start();
        consumerThread.Start();
    }

    public void StartProducer()
    {
        while (!stop)
        { 
            //wait for an external event to happen 
            //Data data = eventHandler() : How to wait for an event and get?
            Enqueue(data);
        }
    }
}
```

In the other side, I have a method in another class that handles an external event  independantly.

```
public void OnExternalEvent()
{
    //event occured 
    //how to notify and send data to the producer thread?
}
```

My question in not about the producer/consumer pattern, but it's about integrating events among it.

The code I posted is just to make my question clearer, I added two concrete questions in comments.

I would appreciate if anyone can tell me how to do it. I am new in C# and do not have a strong background with event handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ditch your custom synchronized queue and use a [BlockingCollection< T >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

With `BlockingCollection`, you don't have separate threads controlling the queue. Rather, you have a queue, and threads can directly enqueue or dequeue items. The data structure itself handles any concurrency issues, and does non-busy waits when trying to dequeue.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19848796/56778 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19823345/56778 for examples, or just search around a bit. Also, see my [Simple Multithreading blog post](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/07/18/simple-multithreading-part-2/) for a little bit more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Just consider using Rx [(Reactive extensions)](http://www.introtorx.com/) for that. They are modern, flexible, convenient, support multithreading and, simply, just cool. he he

With using `IObservable<T>` collections you just subscribe to them and receive notifications if something changes (is posted) into them.

This is how you post the data:

```
var subject = new Subject<string>();
subject.OnNext("Value");
subject.OnCompleted();
```

This is how subscribing:

```
subject.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread);  // this is for thread safety, for instance
subject.Subscribe(() => { /* some action */ });
```

*Oh, and, also, all that is thread safe!*

Comment: Thank you for these tips, I would have preferred a .Net standard solution. I will consider using it if there is no other way.

Comment: Well, Rx -- is not just some third-party libraries. Even though it is not included into .NET standard "package", it's still the same as ASP.NET MVC, if to speak of "standarding" (and is developing by Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc.). You can understand that just noticing that the components "live" in `System.Reactive` namespace (which is "alowed" by Microsoft not for any library).